# How do I make a pre task execute regardless of what tags are passed in?

Tags: ansible

```
---    
- name: superduper playbook
  hosts: aws-region1
  remote_user: mesrine
  pre_tasks:
  - include_vars: "{{ env }}/group_vars/vancouver"
    when: region is defined and region == 'van'
  ...snipped...
```

I want the `include_vars` task to execute regardless of whatever tags that are passed in. Right now, any tags that are passed in, are filtering out my `include_vars` pre task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always use the [special tag](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags) - `always` - to force a task to always run regardless of the tags specified.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you

Comment: For clarity, can you apply tags to all of the pre-tasks similar to applying them to a block? or would you need to nest them inside of a block?